# Printing to thermal printer in python

Tags: python

I have been trying to print on a POS printer and a label printer, depending on the running function. Here is where I am at:

```
import win32print, win32ui, win32con
    
# X from the left margin, Y from top margin 
# both in pixels
X=50; Y=50
# Separate lines from Your string 
# for example:input_string and create 
# new string for example: multi_line_string 
# @@@@@@@
lable = Lable.objects.all().last()
# @@@@@@@
multi_line_string = label_text.splitlines() 
the_name_will_appear_on_printer_spool = str(f"print_job{lable.id}") 
hDC = win32ui.CreateDC ()
# Set default printer from Windows:
# hDC.CreatePrinterDC (win32print.GetDefaultPrinter ())
hDC.CreatePrinterDC(win32print.OpenPrinter("EPSON LX-350 ESC/P"))
hDC.StartDoc (the_name_will_appear_on_printer_spool)
hDC.StartPage ()
for line in multi_line_string:
   hDC.TextOut(X,Y,line)             
   Y += 50
    
   print(hDC.TextOut.text())
   hDC.EndPage ()
   hDC.EndDoc ()
   message.success(request, 'Test printer job send')
```

I have been using `p = win32print.OpenPrinter("EPSON LX-350")` to grab a specific printer but in this case i need to use something like this: `hDC.CreatePrinterDC (win32print.OpenPrinter("EPSON LX-350"))`. The problem is I'm getting this error: `Objects of type 'PyHANDLE' can not be converted to Unicode.`

Since i grabbed this from a 2013 answer there may be a better way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This part has nothing to do with Django, but since I'm developing in Django, I just thought someone with Django knowledge might have some helpful insights in Python. I'm sorry if you feel like being misled.

Comment: What is `printers`? Also, it's probably important for you to have a very clear understanding of the parameter types required for all the functions you are using, as well as the return value. For instance, `win32print.OpenPrinter` returns a handle; does `CreatePrinterDC` take a handle as input? I can't find any information saying it does. I know it's code from an old answer but maybe it's better to try to gain a deeper understanding of the underlying functions and structures.

Answer (score 0):

After some trials and errors, a lot of googling, I decided to use this:

```
printer_name = "MXP T11"
raw_data = bytes(label_text, "utf-8") 

drivers = win32print.EnumPrinterDrivers(None, None, 2)
hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)
printer_info = win32print.GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2)
for driver in drivers:
    if driver["Name"] == printer_info["pDriverName"]:
        printer_driver = driver

raw_type = "XPS_PASS" if printer_driver["Version"] == 4 else "RAW"

try:
    hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, ("test of raw data", None, raw_type))
    try:
        win32print.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter)
        win32print.WritePrinter(hPrinter, raw_data)
        win32print.EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)
    except Exception as e:
        win32print.EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)
        message.warning(request, f"Error! {e}")
                
except Exception as e:
    win32print.ClosePrinter(hPrinter)
    message.warning(request, f'Error! {e}')
```